# How does hibernate use an empty string for an equality restriction?

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

I have a column that potentially has some bad data and I can't clean it up, so I need to check for either null or empty string.  I'm doing a Hibernate Criteria query so I've got the following that returns incorrectly right now:

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Criteria myCriteria = session.createCriteria(Object);
...
myCriteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("stringColumn"),
                               Restrictions.eq("stringColumn", "")));
List<Objects> list = myCriteria.list();
```

I can't get it to properly return the results I'd expect.  So as an experiment I changed the second restriction to read:

```
 Restrictions.eq("stringColumn", "''")
```

And it started returning the expected results, so is hibernate incorrectly translating my empty string (e.g. "") into a SQL empty string (e.g. ''), or am I just doing this wrong?

Comment: Which database are you using - empty strings have differing behaviour in different dbs

Answer (score 5):

With HSQL (and Derby) and the following values:

```
insert into FOO values (1, 'foo');
insert into FOO values (2, 'bar');
insert into FOO values (3,  NULL);
insert into FOO values (4, '');
```

You criteria query

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("name"), 
                         Restrictions.eq("name", "")));
crit.list();
```

returns:

```
Foo [id=3, name=null]
Foo [id=4, name=]
```

As expected.

What database are you using? Could it be Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're doing it wrong. `null` in Java maps to `NULL` in SQL, and empty String (`""`) in Java maps to empty string in SQL (`''`)