# Hibernate empty string for an equality restriction for PostgreSQL 8.3 and Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, postgresql, criteria

Extending on
[How does hibernate use an empty string for an equality restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813138/how-does-hibernate-use-an-empty-string-for-an-equality-restriction)

I am having a problem about how to check for an empty string between Oracle 11g and PostgreSQL
using Hibernate Restriction

For my specific application,
PostgreSQL saves empty value using 2 single quotes '' 
while Oracle saves empty value as NULL

The code to check whether the value is empty of not is

```
 public void AssureNotEmpty() { ...

     //For Oracle 11g    
     valueRestriction = Restrictions.isNotNull(propertyValueAlias);


     //For PostgreSQL
     valueRestriction = Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNotNull(propertyValueAlias),
                        Restrictions.ne(propertyValueAlias, ""));
```

Restrictions.ne(propertyValueAlias, "") fails on Oracle when the value is NOT empty because it will be interpreted as value != NULL (which will ALWAYS be false) as Hibernate makes Oracle interprets "" as NULL.

So how can I make the function Database-platform agnostic (because now I have to detect which database is running, PostgreSQL or Oracle)?

Or am I completely misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

Use `nullif(val, '')` when storing the values to coerce Postgres to behave like Oracle